# Jenkins "Multibranch Pipeline Project" Tutorial Error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I'm following [**this tutorial**](https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-multibranch-pipeline-project/) on the Jenkins official docs.

> This tutorial shows you how to use Jenkins to orchestrate building and
>   testing a simple **Node.js** and **React** application with the Node Package
>   Manager (npm), as well as deliver different outcomes for development
>   and production purposes.

Everything was pretty straight forward, but I came across this error when I got to "*Run your Pipeline on the production branch*" portion of the guide, [link here](https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-multibranch-pipeline-project/#run-your-pipeline-on-the-production-branch).

Error Received

```
+ sleep 1
+ ./node_modules/serve/bin/serve.js -c 0 -s build
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Aviato-Team_production-OZ2WCGEMEZUSDYGKYBCG4BWFXFVS2KVB47HNPHOYCFLEP7JEO52Q/node_modules/serve/bin/serve.js:83

detect(port).then(async open => {
                  ^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:611:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:387:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:153:9)

+ echo 193
+ set +x

Now...
Visit http://localhost:5000 to see your Node.js/React application in action.
(This is why you specified the "args -p 5000:5000" parameter when you
created your initial Pipeline as a Jenkinsfile.)
```

I followed their guide step by step, using their very own repository and setup code. The only thing I changed was that instead of creating a pipeline with `Git`, instead I'm using `GitHub`, as noted [here in the guide](https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-multibranch-pipeline-project/#create-your-pipeline-project-in-blue-ocean).

When I navigate to `http://localhost:5000` nothing shows up.

Some things to note (in case it helps):

1. My docker is installed on Windows 10 OS
2. I'm using GitHub as opposed to Git (already mentioned)
3. Tutorial is using BlueOcean to create pipeline

How do I fix this error? I'm still learning and following this guide, so since this error is out of my control I'm not sure how to fix it.

**Edit:** My terminal on my Win10 machine is outputting this if it helps:

```
Apr 20, 2018 4:02:23 AM com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform$JdkWithJettyBootPlatform getSelectedProtocol
INFO: ALPN callback dropped: SPDY and HTTP/2 are disabled. Is alpn-boot on the boot class path?
Apr 20, 2018 4:04:40 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.input.POSTHyperlinkNote <init>
WARNING: You need to define the root URL of Jenkins
Apr 20, 2018 4:04:40 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.input.POSTHyperlinkNote <init>
WARNING: You need to define the root URL of Jenkins
```

[**Here's my GitHub**](https://github.com/philliprognerud/Aviato-Team/tree/production) if you want to see the production branch code.

Comment: It seems as though from this [Jenkins Issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46840) the user was having the same output when he was using a MacOS, then they switched to Ubuntu machine which fixed the problem. So is this related to my Win10 machine?

Comment: I can verify that the problem is with `./node_modules/serve/bin/serve.js -c 0 -s build`, I ran the exact same guide through on a Linux Server. Got the same error. I went to go check what was in `serve.js`, and there's literally nothing. I'm doing `vim serve.js` inside of the docker shell.

Comment: GitHub runs on Git.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the node.js version that is used to run/build your project is not supporting the *async arrow function* construction that is used in `./node_modules/serve/bin/serve.js`. This should be supported in Node version [7.10.1](http://node.green/#ES2017-features-async-functions-async-arrow-functions) and higher.

You probably should start with changing your build to include a `node -v` command so you can check if the node version actually is the problem.

If this is the case you'll need to update the node version in the container. Doing this in Docker is not trivial if you've not done it before. I'd say your best options are to either change the state of the current container by starting a shell in the container and manually updating node, or create your own Dockerfile based on [jenkinsci/blueocean](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/blueocean/).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little old, but you need to update the docker image to `node:9-alpine` in your `Jenkinsfile`.

See [this documentation](https://github.com/jenkins-docs/building-a-multibranch-pipeline-project/issues/10) for full details.